# SWIG: python callback with function template and shared pointer as return value

Tags: python, boost, swig, shared-ptr

I'm creating wrappers using SWIG for python for my software library and I have the following function:

```
    template<class PR>
    boost::shared_ptr<JobT<PR> > Client::WaitForJob() {
        boost::shared_ptr<JobT<PR> > job;
        while (!job.get()) {
            list<boost::shared_ptr<Job> > jobs = GetJobs(p_jobName, p_jobID, "", JobT<PR>::New);
            while (jobs.size() > 0) {
                job = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<JobT<PR> >(jobs.front());
                jobs.pop_front();
                if (ClaimJob(job)) return job;
                else job.reset();
            }
        }
        return job;
    }
```

In this case I'm able to create a class for the JobT and I also used the boos_pointer.
Currently I have the following in my interface file:

%template(jobme)     JobT;
%include "boost_shared_ptr.i" 
%shared_ptr(jobme)

%template(waitforme) Client::WaitForJob;

The waitforme function template return a pointer to a swig python object. This is correct but i want it to be the same as a jobme pointer.

Can someone point out if this is possible ??

Answer (score 1):

The Swig object you get back is a proxy for the `jobme`.  It should work just like a `JobT` wherever you need it.

Ah, I think I see the problem.  You need to instantiate the `JobT` and `Client::WaitForJob` for each `PR` you have:

```
%include "boost_shared_ptr.i"
%shared_ptr(JobT<Foo>);

#include <JobT.hpp>
%template(Job##NAME) JobT<Foo>;
%template Client::WaitForJob<Foo>;
```

So `%template` instantiates a template, but it doesn't guess all the possible types you might use to instantiate it with.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you... only 12 years later and this awesome answer gets its first upvote. I had spent a day bashing my head against a SWIG-shaped wall, this has resolved it for me.

Comment: Glad to have helped, @StackG. I don't use SWIG any more, as our group decided that it's just a bit too magical and you get a bunch of little obscure problems like this. We're now using pybind11, which I recommend. The bindings are explicit, which means you have to declare everything (there's no parsing of your headers to declare things for you), but it means that everything you declare is there, and only what you declare.